# Android application force close

Tags: android, sms

Trying to send a text message more than 100 times, is there any way to override the SMSDispatcher text limitation?

Here's the error:

```
08-02 03:34:07.927: WARN/dalvikvm(1199): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleReachSentLimit(SMSDispatcher.java:809)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleMessage(SMSDispatcher.java:339)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-02 03:34:07.927: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code -- updated:

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText PhNumber, Message, TxtCount;
Button btnSendSMS;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    //create text box to enter phone number
    PhNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhNumber);        
    //create text box to enter message
    Message=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message);        
    //create text box to see how many times the user wants to send message
    TxtCount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtCount);
    //create button to send text message
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    //create listener for button
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {               
        public void onClick(View v)
            {           
                //variable for count.
                int count = 1;
                //variable for text message
                String msg = Message.getText().toString();
                //create string array of the alphabet
                String[] mArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
                        "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "r", "x", "y", "z"};
                //create variable to hold random number
                final Random r = new Random();
                //variable for phone number
                String num = PhNumber.getText().toString();
                //create array of the phone number to get the number of numbers entered.
                char[] nArray = num.toCharArray();
                //variable for the amount of text messages to send.
                String max1 = TxtCount.getText().toString();
                //variable to watch button and hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //test to see if number has a value
                 if (num.equals("") || (nArray.length < 10))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter 10 digit phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                //test to see if msg has a value
                if (msg.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }           
                //test to see if there's a number of times to text
                if (max1.equals("") || (Integer.parseInt(TxtCount.getText().toString()) <= 0))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a number more than zero to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }               
                //if all fields have valid data -- send text message until count = max  
                int max = Integer.parseInt(TxtCount.getText().toString());
                while (count <= max) {
                    //create variable to hold random letter of the alphabet
                    String rLetter = mArray[r.nextInt(25)];
                    String rLetter2 = mArray[r.nextInt(25)];
                    String rLetter3 = mArray[r.nextInt(25)];
                    String rLetter4 = mArray[r.nextInt(25)];
                    final Random i = new Random();
                    sendSMS(num, (rLetter3 + i.nextInt(100) + rLetter4 + " " + msg + " " + rLetter + i.nextInt(100) +rLetter2));
                    count++;
                };
                //hide the keyboard
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(TxtCount.getWindowToken(), 0);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(PhNumber.getWindowToken(), 0);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Message.getWindowToken(), 0);
                //set phone number to ""
                PhNumber.setText("");
                //set message to ""
                Message.setText("");
                //set count to ""
                TxtCount.setText("");
                //refocus on phone number
                PhNumber.requestFocus();                    
            }           
    });        
}
 //sends a sms message to another device
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {       
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: well it will give exception at these lines
 if (TxtCount.getText().toString() == "")
 else if (num == "")
 else if (msg == "")
A string must be checked with equalIgnoreCase("");
change it and see the result

Comment: Post your stack trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare string with ==
try this

```
if (TxtCount.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number of times to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (num.queals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a phone number to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (msg.equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

while (count <= max) 
{                  
    sendSMS(""+num,""+ msg);
    count++;
};
```

Like this

```
else if (num.equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a phone number to nuke!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: That's right, but it's not the issue which is causing the application to be force closed. There is some NullPointerException somewhere

Comment: He has to check his layout file while accessing by findViewById.I guess he messed with spelling

Comment: Did you check spelling of the view in layout file

Comment: Everything works just fine when you enter information it's just when nothing is entered in the boxes that it is force closing .. well that and if it's over a certain amount of times you want to send it -- Yes all my spelling is correct

Comment: can you send a message without a phoneNumber?

Comment: You can't call   sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI)
this method with phoneNumber null,it will force close then

Comment: handle this,don't call the method with phoneNumber is null.

Comment: well isn't that what i'm trying to do with the nested if block for validation?

Comment: after validation just put a return;As you didn't put return it is calling sendSMS with invalid input

Comment: mm put the return in but still force closing, sigh it's already 1AM i have work in 7 hours lol.

Comment: Yes i put it in all of my if statements

Comment: seems like no problem.can you put your main.xml